# map<string, object> sort according to object member function value

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload the greater than operator of a class I wrote (to resemble a real case I'm facing) to sort a class member map.

Here I made a tar ball with my code:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=81335448529630428273

In the `MapSorting` class there is

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<Electrons> > m_mymap;
```

I'm interest in sorting in decreasing order the map using the `Electron::pt()` member function so that, if I do

```
std::vector<Electrons> veto_electrons = m_mymap["Veto"];
```

then `veto_electrons[0]` is always the electron with highest `pt`.

I could probably write a functor to do the job, but, mainly as a drill, I wanted to try to overload the `operator <` if possible.

Also would be nice to have some feedback on my code from real programmers, I'm not a professional but I like and enjoy programming!

Comment: `std::map<std::string, boost::flat_set<Electrons>>`

Comment: BTW, it's super inconvenient to provide your code in a tarball. Use ideone.com or some other platform that lets us view and test it without downloading random files from strangers on the Internet.

Comment: Not downloading any tarballs it sounds like you're trying to use the wrong tool for the job. `std::map` only calls `operator <` on insertions. When overloading `operator <` you need to provide an implementation that is a consistent, i.e. if `a` < `b` at time t, then `a` must be < `b` at time t + n.

Comment: My plan of spreding my malicious code failed! Btw, I didn't know ideone.com, thanks, next time I'll use that! Thanks for the explanation Andreas, I now see the point. I could simply sort the vector before inserting it in the map, I guess its the easiest way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enforce that the elements in the map are sorted, then the simplest (from writing the least amount of code perspective) might be just to override the insertion method in map and just use it:

```
class my_map
: public std::map<std::string, std::vector<Electrons>
{
    // whatever constructors you need here

    std::pair<iterator, bool>
    insert(value_type vt)
    {
        // make sure the vector<Electrons> is sorted!
        std::sort(vt.second.begin(), vt.second.end(), 
            [](const Electrons& a, const Electrons& b){
                return a.pt() > b.pt();
            });

        // then insert it
        return std::map<std::string, std::vector<Electrons>>::insert(vt);
    }
};
```

Now, a lot of people here may consider this "bad practice" since `std::map` doesn't provide a virtual destructor so it shouldn't be inherited from. So don't make a `std::map<...>*` that you dynamically initialize to `my_map`. Alternatively, you could make `my_map` have a `std::map<...>` member and do the same thing - but that requires a ton more typing and basically copying over the entire interface. I would do it this way.

**Note**: I didn't override `operator[]`. So don't use that for inserting.

Comment: Thanks @Barry I guess I'm just gonna order the `vector` before inserting it in the `map`. I thing I understood that its not actually possible to overload the `operator <` in this case because `map` is ordered upon insertion and thus I would have to basically write it to a `vector of pairs`, `sort` it and reverse to a `map`!